# Difficulty constructing a sentence that reflect the interview process and targets entry levels

Tags: word-choice, grammar, american-english, sentence, syntactic-analysis

English is not my first language, and I do struggle here and there.

I would like to come up with a sentence that would reflect the followings:

Reduce your technical interviews in half. That is for many entry level developers / software engineering position. Many candidates have to undergo 3-5 interviews, and I want to convey that I aim to reduce your interview time by at least half.

- Also make the point clear that I am targeting entry levels for the tech sector.

I am not sure how to word out or even maybe i should break into pieces. Have a heading, and subheading.

Any suggestion greatly welcome.

**My attempts:**

This will be slogan used for my website, in trying to market to my potential audience (recruiters, HR manager)

Slogan: Reduce your interviews in half (big heading)

Our system instantly provide you with our best available candidate (small heading)

Comment: That's a writing question. Until you make an attempt to write it, we can't assess the grammar or usage, or make suggestions.  As for purpose and audience, Is this to be a marketing brochure, or what?

Comment: thanks Brian. I have made an update to my initial post with my attempt, along with purpose and audience if any other clarification is required please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

> Don’t search applicants. Find qualified staff at a glance.

Comment: thank you. should i also have a subheading to specifiy that this web app that allows anyone to hire the best

Comment: I think that the sub-heading shall define the plus of your website. Something more technical, like "A simplified  recruitment process: our system  halves the number of interviews by a selection of the most appropriate candidate(s). .

Comment: thank you. would it make sense if i said Don’t screen applicants. Receive qualified staff at a glance. this is because they still have to search for a canddiate just that the entire process has been simplified and greatly reduce

Comment: sorry for this last comment, but does this still hold if the only work available is remote work. such finding qualified staff for your remote task

Comment: A catchy slogan must be clear and creative. The appropriateness to the effective process is secondary. The benefits of your web site (i.e. process simplificatio, remote work only) may be summarized in the small heading.

Answer (score 0):

- Reduce your interviews in half.

This is not correct grammar in AmE.  You would say either:

- Reduce your interview time **by** [one-] half!
  or
- **Cut** your interview time in half!

or, if you mean that the *number* of interviews can be halved:

- Eliminate half of your interviews!

================

- Our system instantly provides you with our best available candidate.

This one strikes me odd as well, because it seems to be saying you won't supply "your" (the client's) best candidate, or **the** best candidate, but rather "our" (Jon's company's) best candidate. I would expect your system to promise **the** best candidate, by identifying him/her immediately. Like this:

- Our system **{lets you/helps you/enables you to}** instantly **identify the** best available candidate.